# Create a shell script to logon to a server and email disk usage

Tags: command-line, server, email

I would like to create a shell script that it will login to a server, get the disk usage from the server, email to me, and then exit from server. Also, if possible to do it daily. This is what I have:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

ssh -p 1111 server@server.example.com

CURRENT=$(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')

mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' username@example.com << EOF
Disk usage is at:  $CURRENT%
EOF
fi
```

the name of the shell script is example.sh
When I run it, it keeps asking me for password and once I am logged in nothing happens.

Comment: Are you on Ubuntu? `bash` is at `/bin/bash`, not in `/usr/bin`. And did you mean to run the commands after `ssh` at the server?

Comment: yes I am on Ubuntu. Well, I want the .sh to connect to the server and also to check the disk usage that it is on the server and then email that information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly to explain why nothing happens, most likely because of the syntax. Your ssh command is of the form: `ssh server`, which is when you only want to login, and then manually type some commands interactively. But if you want some command to be run automatically after login, you should be doing : `ssh server somecommand`, so just having `somecommand` on the next line will not work.

Well, if you want a system to both email disk space info whenever you want, and at the same time support scheduled emails, I would recommend a three part system:

- one script on the server that obtains the disk info and email logic, for example at `/home/yourusername/script.sh`
- crontab to run the script.sh
- for your arbitrary, on-a-whim requests you can ssh and execute the script

### script.sh

This is the script you put on the server, for example at /home/yourusername/script.sh.

```
#!/bin/bash

s="Disk Space Alert: $(df / | grep / | awk '{ print $5}')"

mail -s $s username@example.com

# Feedback
echo $s
```

I removed the `sed` because it simply removed `%` sign but then you were adding it back later, this seems a redundant use of sed so I removed it.

Secondly, I have condensed the disk usage info to fit just in the subject line, if this doesn't work then of course you can revise it to your original form, but let everyone know either way so we can learn if there were any errors etc

### crontab

Edit crontab on your server, for example ssh into your server and then proceed with these commands

```
$ crontab -e
```

You know the format is

```
# m h dom mon dow  command
```

so for daily every day 8 am

```
0 8 * * * /home/yourusername/script.sh
```

So as long as you have tested the script already and know it works to send emails, then crontab will run the script and cause the email to be sent at 8 am every day

### arbitrary request to get disk info emailed

You just ssh but put the script command on the end

```
ssh -p 1111 server@server.example.com /home/yourusername/script.sh
```

This uses ssh syntax `ssh server somecommand` so it logs in, executes whatever command and returns results to your local standard out.

Because it has the feedback line, not only should it email, but you also see the `Disk Space Alert: ...` message so that you at least get immediate feedback that your script was run or not.

Comment: so I don't really understand this part "for your arbitrary, on-a-whim requests you can ssh and execute the script. " Do I have to create another .sh ? or just put it at the bottom of script.sh?

Comment: Not at all, you see the cron and script lets it run automatically daily, but in addition to that, if for some reason there is some emergency for example suddenly your boss demands this info right now. Then you cannot wait for tomorrow to get this info. So in this case I am saying you can also open a terminal on your local computer and run that command to manually trigger that same script.

Answer (score 3):

First, generate a public key for use to log-in to the remote system without a password:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_username"
```

This will generate a 4096-bit RSA key in your `~/.ssh/` directory with your user-name as the label. Then, add this new key to your ssh-agent so that it is used when you connect via SSH.

```
ssh-agent -s
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

If you set a custom name during key generation, replace `id_rsa` with that name.

Now, copy your public key contents to your clipboard.

```
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

Next, log-in to the remote server with `ssh -p YOURPORT user@remote.host` and edit the remote user's `authorized_keys` file.

```
vim .ssh/autorized_keys
```

Paste in the contents you just copied to your clipboard.  This allows connections from your computer to the remote host without password, instead using certificates (usually much more secure, anyway).

Now, you need to make a script, `example-script.sh`, in your remote host's home directory(make sure to `chmod a+x example-script.sh` afterward to set it as executable).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
CURRENT=$(df / | awk '/\// { print $5}' | sed 's/%//g')
mail -s 'Disk Space Alert' username@example.com << EOF
Disk usage is at:  $CURRENT%
EOF
```

And now, create a script in your local home directory, `local-script.sh` to run the command later easily(again, make sure to make it executable after).

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
ssh -P YOURPORT user@remote.host ./example-script.sh
```

This script allows you to run `./local-script.sh` from your home directory to run your remote script in just one line. You can then add this as an alias to your `.bashrc` file so that you can just run `local-script` or whatever other alias you may want. You can also use the absolute path(`/home/your_username/local-script.sh`) in `crontab` to make it run at a specific time every day.